# Where is the bundle & the dist folder in html-webpack-plugin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have the following Webpack config with the `html-webpack-plugin`:

```
/*
    ./webpack.config.js
*/
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});


module.exports = {
  entry: './client/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

But I cannot find the actual bundle that is created in the end. Neither can I find the dist folder. Where is all of that?

I would also be keen on removing this plugin again, but all the tutorials I can find online include it. It makes it really difficult for me as a beginner who doesn't know webpack, to include file paths in my react code and style sheets.

Comment: webpack devserver internally compiles your files to memory and serves them from there for performance. You would need to run your build task to see the files physically. You almost never need to check the bundles though, why do you need to? You also certainly can write your own html file it's not hard, just add the `index_bundle.js` script and add whatever element react is attaching to.

Comment: If you're a beginner trying to get started with React, I'd highly recommend just using Facebook's [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) tool.

Comment: path.resolve uses the current working directory Kyle

Comment: @DominicTobias Thanks a lot. But if this is just served from memory, how do I know where to put my css files and images, that is, how do i reference them now?

Comment: You put them anywhere you like and reference them relatively in the js file e.g. `import './MyComponent.css'` (NB there is a way to do absolute paths but relative is simpler) - you need to decide what you are using e.g. postcss, sass, css modules, plain css - there are webpack loaders for each that need to be added to your webpack.config file - google for example "webpack css loader" or "webpack css modules"

Comment: thanks. i will do that. i think i will also do away with the html-webpack thing for now. and what exactly do you mean by "just add the 'index_bundle.js' script" ? I guess you mean the script tag in the main html file. However, my problem is that I do not get any output, I don't have a dist file neither a index_bundle - I just don't know where everything is. (I'm talking after I removed the html-webpack plugin). My output is still `output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },`, but it just won't spit anything out! :( (and I have created the `dist` folder)